# Window DataContext or ElementName

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently facing a little problem with specifing or not specifing the datacontext of a window, and why there is a difference between various methods. Hope you can help me out.

Lets start with some code to show my problem. This is the code behind for my TestWindow.xaml.cs, nothing really special about it just a simple string property

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    private string _helloWorld = "Hello World!";

    public string HelloWorld
    {
        get { return _helloWorld; }
        set { _helloWorld = value; }
    }

    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

This code will be the same for all 3 following XAML layouts, so no changes behind the code only in XAML.

1.) Databinding with given ElementName

```
<Window x:Class="Ktsw.Conx.ConxClient.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        Name="TestWin">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HelloWorld, ElementName=TestWin}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

2.) Databinding with specifing DataContext on Window

```
<Window x:Class="Ktsw.Conx.ConxClient.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HelloWorld}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

3.) Neither ElementName nor specifing DataContext

```
<Window x:Class="Ktsw.Conx.ConxClient.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HelloWorld}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The first two methods work just fine, but why fails the 3rd?

In the first method I am not specifing the DataContext and it works automatically, in the second method I am not specifing the ElementName and it works, but without declaring one of those it fails. Why would it fail getting both automatically, but work fine with getting each individually?

Comment: Could you specify what "works just fine" and "fails" mean in this context? Does it not compile? does it show errors? does it throw exceptions? does it crash your computer?

Comment: @Default works just fine = displays the text "Hello World!" in the textblock
fails = does not display the text (stays empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the Remarks for the [Binding.Source property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx). The binding source is the object on which to look up the property specified by `Path` (HelloWorld). `ElementName`, `RelativeSource`, and `Source` set the binding source. If they are null, the source is the DataContext of the element that you are binding (TextBlock). If an element's DataContext is not explicitly set, it's inherited from a containing element.

In the first case, any DataContext is irrelevant to the TextBlock binding, because the source is being set explicitly through ElementName.

In the second case, a DataContext is necessary to specify a source because it is not being set explicitly through ElementName, RelativeSource, or Source. TextBlock's DataContext is not set, so Window's is inherited.

In the third case, there is no explicit source and no DataContext to inherit, so the source is null and binding fails. There is no default source.

Answer (score 2):

`{Binding}` by default always refers to the `DataContext`.

In your first example you simply deactivate the default behavior by using elementName, this uses the element as source then.

In your second example you explicitly change the `DataContext`to point at your Window.

So in the last example the `{Binding HelloWorld}` tries to convert `null` into and Object with a HelloWorld property which fails.

Answer (score 1):

It is working in 1st and 2nd case because `TextBlock` is able to find `HelloWorld` property

In 1st case you are specifying `ElemtnName` so `TextBlock` will refer to `Window` and search for property `HelloWorld` in Window class.

In 2nd case you are specifying `DataContext` of Window so `Textblock` will inherit that and will look for `HelloWorld` property in `DataContext` i.e. again `Window` class

In 3rd case you aren't specifying anything so TextBlock is unable to find `HelloWorld` property

> In 1st case I am not specifing a DataContext so why should it know
>   what to get?

When you are setting `ElementName`, `TextBlock` will try to find `HelloWorld` from that element

> In 2nd case I am not specifing what it should get?

You are setting the `DataContext` of it's parent that is `Window` so it automatically inherits that and you are telling it to extract `HelloWorld` property from `DataContext`

Comment: In 1st case I am not specifing a DataContext so why should it know what to get? In 2nd case I am not specifing what it should get?

If you compare them both, in 1st case the window knows what DataContext it has so it not inherit it to the TextBlock without the ElementName but when I explicit say what the DataContext is - it can than inherit the DataContext correctly without the need of ElementName.

Comment: ElementName does not set the DataContext, it simply changes the Binding Source.

Answer (score 0):

The third fails because the `DataContext` is not *inferred.* If you wanted the third to work, you'd do something like this:

```
public TestWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

It doesn't know *anything* about the path `HelloWorld` because it doesn't have a `DataContext`.

Comment: The first method also has no DataContext specified so why does it work?

Comment: Because you told it to not use the DataContext, with elementName

Comment: @RandRandom, because you're specifying the source to pull it from when you grab the `Window` element. Armed with that, the WPF data binding engine can look for the path `HelloWorld` on that element.